# Embeding SSRS report viewer in Delphi

Tags: delphi, reporting-services

Perhaps this question is naive, as I am just starting with ssrs. This is a large Delphi (2009) application that currently uses Crystal (activex) for reports. We are wanting to move to ssrs but would still like to control the report parameters from within our app as we've done with crystal. I've seen the Report Viewer Control for a VS environment and I'd like to do something like that. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt you can - as far as I know, the ReportViewer control comes in two .NET flavors: one for ASP.NET web applications, and one for Windows Forms .NET apps.

**However:** you can access all of the reporting server stuff using a simple web browser control, too. SSRS has extensive support for specifying just about anything in the URL, too.

Check out the MSDN docs on [Using URL Access from a Windows (Win32) application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms154537.aspx) for a starting point.

Or if you want to take it a step further, the Reporting Services also expose standard web services to do just about anything (including managing SSRS), which you should have no trouble consuming in Delphi as regular SOAP web services.

For that, see the MSDN docs on [Using the SOAP API in a Windows Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155131.aspx).